# Subimage matching on b&w images

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, opencv

I'm trying to detect a subimage (Slave image) within a larger image(Master/Base Image) that is only black and white pixels, and then outline the match with a red rectangle. The images are almost always squares or rectangles.

I have looked at cv2 and PIL with template matching, but it never works correctly, instead outlining the entire image as a match, not the specific matched area. Additionally, the image sizes are different, so I have looked at multi-scale template matching and it still doesn't work for my need.

So, the question I have is, because I'm just dealing with b&w and straight lines that run into each-other, like the images attached, is there just not enough differentiated information between the images to make an accurate match?  Alternatively, is there a ML approach that could be taken beyond object recognition?

Doug

[image: Master/Base Image]

[image: Subimage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sub-image search algorithms work by sliding the sub-image over the main image and testing how well they compare at every possible location. Since your sub-image is the same size as your main image, there is only a single location where the sub-image can lie on top of the main image - that is when they are exactly aligned. So you need to **trim** your sub-image first.

Here I do it with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal:

```
magick compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search haystack.png needle.png locations.png
```

and there is no result. But if I trim it first and then retry:

```
magick needle.png -trim +repage trimmed-needle.png
magick compare -metric RMSE -subimage-search haystack.png trimmed-needle.png locations.png
```

I get:

```
949,638
```

which means a perfect match at those coordinates.

**TLDR;** You need to trim your sub-image to the smallest possible size and it will work.

Comment: @ Mark Setchell  Thank you. Yes, that was it.  However, some of my images are 2k. What would you recommend for faster processing? Is template matching with cv2 usually faster?

Comment: OpenCV is generally faster than ImageMagick, yes. You will help yourself considerably if you can get both the images smaller yet still have the salient features visible - it will be hard with thin lines as they tend to disappear on shrinking.